# segfault in critical section - avoiding deadlock

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, deadlock

I am asked following question in an Interview:

1) There are two threads: T1 and T2. They are sharing one resources and to avoid deadlock using pthread_mutex for synchronizing. How you will design your code such that if any segmentation fault happen after T1 enters critical section, T2 will not be in deadlock?

```
//T1 Code
try 
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(somelock);
    .... 
    /// work on shared memory
    //What will happen if segfault happens here?
    .... 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(somelock);
} catch(...)
{
   pthread_mutex_unlock(somelock);
   // exception happens
}
```

I told I dont know the ans. Interviewer reached this situation waiting for my ans.

Is there really any design to avoid deadlock in this situation?

Above codeblock just for understanding. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367851/when-does-this-happen-thread-suspended-while-in-critical-section). But its not clear
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That `try`/`catch` block is not going to protect against segmentation faults.

Comment: This is why you should use a [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).  When the `lock_guard` goes out of scope the lock gets released automatically.

Comment: Easy - ensure that the protected section is so small, and so simple, and so tested, that the segfault will not happen.

Comment: Stack unwinding is about allocating objects on the stack so that however control exits the method, the object will be cleaned up automatically.  That's nothing to do with a thread dying as a result of receiving a signal, because in that case the method never is exited.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  ok... may be I misinterpreted stack unwinding with this qus......

Comment: Maybe not.  If you install a signal handler so that a segfault doesn't kill the the thread, then perhaps you could use RAII / stack unwinding to clean up.

Comment: Signal handler as John mentioned is the only way I'd think you could do it, and I could be wrong but a lock_guard won't necessarily help either, since a segfault is neither going to invoke dtors nor throw (usually -- I've worked with some weird compilers that would throw on an access violation, but certainly not standard behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the signal with a signal handler and handle the resource as you please.

I could bealive that with his hint the interviewer meant using the RAII idiom - Resource Allocation Is Initialization.

But I am unsure  if this applies to signals...

Comment: If a process / thread terminates as a result of receiving a signal then the stack is not unwound, exit handlers are not called, etc..  The thread simply terminates.  Using RAII to address such a situation would need to involve (1) catching the signal, and (2) avoiding *abrupt* termination.  Thread termination might still be the cleanest behavior, but the affected function might be induced to terminate more cleanly, perhaps by throwing an exception.